# labeling the x-coordinate on the dendrogram in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, dendrogram

I am still a beginner in using matlab. 
I would like to label the x coordinate of the dendrogram but do not know how. 
I had a case where I have data that will be used and stored in an excel file.
An example of the contents of the data.

```
535110084   3.78    4.00    4.00    4.00    4.00    4.00    4.00    3.55    3.28    4.00
535110083   2.36    2.63    3.03    2.89    2.48    4.00    2.35    0.99    2.66    4.00
535110071   3.34    3.81    3.72    4.00    4.00    4.00    3.06    1.90    4.00    3.60
535110061   3.86    4.00    4.00    4.00    4.00    4.00    4.00    3.41    4.00    4.00
535100037   2.00    1.72    0.80    1.22    0.97    1.11    2.83    3.97    1.21    0.97
535100067   1.67    1.01    0.94    2.11    1.12    2.55    2.00    2.12    2.10    1.01
535120020   2.87    3.12    3.25    4.00    4.00    4.00    3.88    2.43    3.83    4.00
535120002   4.00    4.00    3.60    4.00    4.00    4.00    4.00    4.00    4.00    4.00
```

These data will be processed in matlab.
I have code like this.

```
data = xlsread('apasaja.xlsx');
z = linkage(data(:,2:11),'single','euclidean')
dendrogram(z)
```

and dendrogram like this:

[image: dendrogram]

But dendrogram at coordinates x, the label does not change. I want to change the label on the x-coordinate. 
For example in the image data to the x coordinates dendrogram supposed 4 is 535130061, 8 is 535120002 etc. 
How to do it. Thank you

Comment: Check [`xtick`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticks.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple:

```
dendrogram(z,'Labels',num2str(data(:,1)))
```

and you get:

[image: dendo]

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful at all.